# Unicorn restart error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn

When I tried to restart my unicorn it throws following error

> Couldn't reload, starting 'cd /var/www/myapp; bundle exec unicorn -D -c /var/www/myapp/config/unicorn.rb -E production' instead
> /var/www/myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/kgio-2.10.0/lib/kgio.rb:31:in `require': incompatible library version - /var/www/myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/kgio-2.10.0/lib/kgio_ext.so (LoadError)

Can anyone help me out why I am getting this error and how to resolve it?

Comment: It just happened to me too. Banging my head over this for a day now. Did you find any solution?

Comment: No we reconfigured the whole server :(

Answer (score 0):

I had troubled similar issue & I fixed this below way

```
listen 3000, reuseport: true
```

`reuseport: true` to my unicorn.rb

I think will help you

Comment: in my case it is 
listen "/tmp/unicorn.myapp.sock" do i need to add reuseport: true along with this